# Change order of application.inputbox in order to prompt that only if needed?

Tags: vba

this code is for a simple application that has a button on a front end sheet, and then there's hidden data that it references to determine if inputted data = eligible for certain pay based on that data.

example: user inputs `Job1` and cost-center `000054`

code goes in `findnext` and determines that Job1 would be eligible for specific pay and doesn't even need the cost centered entered. Certain cases will require a cost-center, but this one doesn't, only the job.

I don't want the users to get confused by entering a cost center upfront when they don't need to in specific circumstances.

How can I change the ordering in the code to have it find that job, and then if there are cost center values in `offset(,4)` it will prompt another `application.inputbox` to then match specific cost-centers?

I think I need to move:

```
lCC = Application.InputBox("Please provide a cost-center--if needed, otherwise skip this step and click OK", "Cost-Center", Type:=2)
If lCC = "False" Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel
```

after the `select case` statement, but I can't figure that out

Is this even possible?

NEW Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub findJC_CC()

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range
Dim lJobCode As String, lCC As String, sFirst As String
Dim matched As Boolean

Dim answer As Integer

lJobCode = Application.InputBox("Please provide a job code", "Job Code", Type:=2)

If lJobCode = "False" Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

answer = MsgBox("Does job have a CC", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Job Exceptions")

matched = False
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set rFound = wsData.Columns("A").Find(lJobCode, wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)

If answer = vbYes Then

lCC = Application.InputBox("Enter CC", "CC", Type:=2)
If lCC = "False" Then Exit Sub

If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
    sFirst = rFound.Address
    Do

    If rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = lCC Then
        matched = True
        MsgBox "This job is eligible."
        Exit Sub
    End If

Set rFound = wsData.Columns("A").FindNext(rFound)

Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst

If Not matched Then MsgBox "Found but CC not eligible"

Else

MsgBox "Job not found"

End If


ElseIf answer = vbNo Then

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address
        Do

        If rFound.Value = lJC Then
            matched = True
            MsgBox "This job is eligible."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Set rFound = wsData.Columns("A").FindNext(rFound)

    Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst


    Else

    MsgBox "Job not found"

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could detect whether you need to ask for cost center using this code :

> Dim sFirst As String Dim matched As Boolean
>
> lJobCode = Application.InputBox("Please provide a job code", "Job > Code",Type:=2)
>
> If lJobCode = "False" Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel
>
> Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
>
> Set rFound =
> wsData.Columns("A").Find(lJobCode, wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count,
> "A"),
>
> If Not rFound Is Nothing Then exit sub
>
> Do Until rfound Is Nothing
>
> if rfound.offset(0,4)<>"" then costfound=true
>
> rfound = wsData.Columns("A").Find(lJobCode, wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count,
> "A")
>
> Loop
>
> if costfound  then
>
> lCC = Application.InputBox("Please provide a cost-center--if needed,
> otherwise skip this step and click OK", "Cost-Center", Type:=2)
>
> If lCC = "False" Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel
>
> end if

Comment: Lets say rFound has 4 rows. 1-3 have `offset(,4).value <> ""` but row 4 has a value in `offset(,4).value`, wouldn't this just look at the `sFirst` address and determine whether it matches the criteria or not?

Comment: You are right , it would just check the first row , we will need to do the loop  with all the found rows, will edit my post shortly to show you how

Comment: I believe this would be a `Do Until ...condition` statement, right?

Comment: yep , you are right , we can use a "do until" loop as you can see in my edited code , I have also added a  variable "costfound" to store whether we found a  cost center, please note I wrote that code without testing it in the vba compiler , so syntax errors may appear

Comment: Also , I think  we should store the "cost centers" we find in the loop ,to limit user answer in the second input box, otherwise the user could later enter any cost center he wants , and I guess it would be wrong , isnt it? sorry I am just now travelling in a train and can show you a debugged script , if u want me can do it later this afternoon when I et back home

Comment: I have an idea, I may implement a Yes/No/Cancel button to determine whether the code needs to populate an input box for a cost center

Comment: umm , may work , but lets say we found 3 cost centers , how is the user going to choose one of them ? what happens is the user enters a wrong cost center?

Comment: so I have an input box where the user can input a cost center. the findnext part keeps searching until both criteria are met, otherwise, it does an `else` msgbox for the appropriate messages. Testing it out now, and the vbYes/No input boxes seem to be working to divide the two sets of jobs

Comment: sounds nice , let me know if you get any problems

Comment: So it works for the `vbYes` section but the ElseIf vbNo section isn't. When it registers my `No` click for a cost-center, it just exits the sub without doing the proper loop. Any ideas?

Comment: nvm, fixed it, had a variable mistyped

Comment: So , is it working fine ? I was checking the code and looked to need some debugging , but if it is already working fine dont need to do anything

Comment: I touched it up a little and it seems to be working just fine, that `vbYesNoCancel` msg prompt seemed to fix my issue

Comment: great! then you fixed it by yourself , any vote to increase my reputation would be appreciated anyway